# HTML. появление блоков при наведении на блок и исчезновение при выходе из всех блоков

Tags: html

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<header class="sticky-top">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id = 'categories'>
    <div class="order-3" id = 'link'>
      Press
    </div>
    <div class="category  order-2 " style = 'opacity:0;'>
      Hot
    </div>
    <div class="category   order-4" style = 'opacity:0;'>
      Easy
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var categories = document.getElementById('categories');
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  var array_category = document.getElementsByClassName('category');

  link.onmouseover = hover;

  categories.onmouseout = out;

  function hover(event){
    for (var i = 0; i < array_category.length; i++){
      array_category[i].style.opacity = '1'
    }
  }
  function out(event){
    for (var i = 0; i < array_category.length; i++){
      array_category[i].style.opacity = '0'
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Использую `Bootstrap4`. Хочу, чтобы когда я наводил на `Press` у меня появлялись `Hot` и `Easy` (что работает), но проблема в том, что , когда курсор выходит за `Press` , то у меня пропадают `Hot` и `Easy`, а я хочу, чтобы они пропадали, только тогда, мышка выйдет за границы всего `header` который занимает всю ширину

Answer (score 0):

```css
.order-3:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
#categories {
    position: relative;
}
.order-3:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css"> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<header class="sticky-top">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id = 'categories'>
    <div class="order-3" id = 'link'>
      Press
    </div>
    <div class="category  order-2 " style = 'opacity:0;'>
      Hot
    </div>
    <div class="category   order-4" style = 'opacity:0;'>
      Easy
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var categories = document.getElementById('categories');
  var link = document.getElementById('link');
  var array_category = document.getElementsByClassName('category');

  link.onmouseover = hover;

  categories.onmouseout = out;

  function hover(event){
    for (var i = 0; i < array_category.length; i++){
      array_category[i].style.opacity = '1'
    }
  }
  function out(event){
    for (var i = 0; i < array_category.length; i++){
      array_category[i].style.opacity = '0'
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```